# How can I update an ASP.NET ListView from the code behind?

Tags: c#, vb.net, listview

I have a `ListView` and an `ObjectDataSource` in my HTML, like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ltwEventos" DataSourceID="odsEventos" runat="server">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        // Some HTML.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        // Some HTML.
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsEventos" EnablePaging="true"
    TypeName="Fotografo2016._Default" SelectMethod="ObterEventos"
    SelectCountMethod="ObterTotalEventos" MaximumRowsParameterName="RegistrosPorPagina"
     StartRowIndexParameterName="IndiceInicial" runat="server">
         <SelectParameters>
             <asp:Parameter Name="IDFotografo" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="140" />
             <asp:Parameter Name="Descricao" Type="String" />
         </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I am populating the `ListView` (using the `ItemDataBound` event) with the first 10 items of my database. That is working fine.

But when the user clicks in a certain button, I want to update the `ListView` with the next 10 items (in the code behind), and show these 20 items in the page. And so on, everytime he clicks in that button, 10 more items are added.

I don't want to select all the items again from my database, I just wanna bring the new 10 items each time and add them to the `ListView`.

I know I can use JavaScript to do that (with an Ajax call), but I'm thinking if I can do it in another way.

I've tried the code above, but this new item does not appear in the page. I'm not very familiar with these components, so I don't know what to do.

```
Private Sub btnBuscaHeader_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuscaHeader.Click
    Dim Test As New ListViewDataItem(Me.ltwEventos.Items.Count, Me.ltwEventos.Items.Count)
    Test.DataItem = "Teste"
    Me.ltwEventos.Items.Add(Test)
End Sub
```

Is it possible to do it using this structure?

PS: I'm using VB, but the answer could be in C# code too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query with something like the ROW_NUMBER (MSSQL SERVER; for other databases, see the equivalent functions), where you determine which rows you want to be returned, preventing a query that records that you have consulted.

See example picking up the lines between numbers 50 and 60:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
WITH OrderedOrders AS  
(  
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,  
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS RowNumber  
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader   
)   
SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate, RowNumber    
FROM OrderedOrders   
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 50 AND 60;
```

Depending of the scenario, the use of Take () and Skip () Linq methods may also be helpful...

Comment: Yeah, I know that and I'm doing in this way. My problem is how to update the list view from the code behind with this new data.

Comment: You can create a method to do the following: 1. Add new items to the DataSource by query; 2. If not set yet, set the DataSource to ListView; 3. Call DataBind() method: ListView.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

This code exemplifies the comment I made in the previous answer:

```
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Person> list = new List<Person>() { new Person("John"), new Person("Louis"), new Person("Walter") };
            Session["DataSource"] = list;
            UpdateListView();
        }

        protected void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            List<Person> list = (List<Person>)Session["DataSource"];
            list.Add(new Person("NewPerson"));
            Session["DataSource"] = list;
            UpdateListView();
        }

        private void UpdateListView()
        {
            ListView1.DataSource = (List<Person>)Session["DataSource"];
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        public Person(string nome)
        {
            _name = nome;
        }
    }
```